# How can I abort an AST visitor and leave the original node unchanged?

Tags: python, python-3.4, abstract-syntax-tree

Using the `ast` and `astor` libraries, I've written a simple script that traverses an AST using `ast.NodeTransformer` and replaces all empty lists with `None`:

```
import ast
import astor


class ListChanger(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_List(self, node):
        if len(node.elts) > 0:
            return ast.copy_location(node, node)
        return ast.copy_location(ast.NameConstant(value=None), node)

x = ast.parse("""["A"]""")
ListChanger().visit(x)
print(astor.to_source(x))

y = ast.parse("""[]""")
ListChanger().visit(y)
print(astor.to_source(y))
```

This works correctly, and outputs:

```
["A"]
None
```

However, I'm unsure of the line that I've used to pull out of the function if the list is empty:

```
return ast.copy_location(node, none)
```

If I replace this with `return`, making the script return `None` if the condition is not met, the node is destroyed rather than being left unchanged, making the first test case print a blank string because the `ast.List` node has been destroyed.

I don't want this to happen, but I also think that using `ast.copy_location(node, node)` seems wrong. Is there a dedicated function to leave the node unchanged and exit the function, or a way to configure `ast.NodeTransformer` so that, if a `visit` function returns `None`, the node remains unchanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer):

> The return value may be the original node in which case no replacement takes place.

So instead of:

```
return ast.copy_location(node, none)
```

just:

```
return node
```